# 3D curve and surface viewing

Tags: feature-request

Some questions pertain to 3D curves and surfaces. When an image is attached with code can one request moderator's support or in another way for viewing by 3D mouse rotation on this site ?

Comment: [LiveGraphics3D](http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/) has not been updated in a long while, and requires Java. If you can find a nice browser-based solution for displaying 3D objects, this request might be a bit better.

Comment: Why not just run the code in Mathematica and manipulate the 3D object in there? I'd rather my browser not consume 400 MB of memory for one page...

Comment: Like in a Walmart you can see displayed items so we can also browse old questions with associated 3D image visibility.

Comment: [three.js](https://threejs.org/) is a great library for displaying 3D objects in (modern) browsers. But writing a Mathematica -> Three converter is probably a lot of work

Comment: @nikie Thanks a lot. This is  more or less what I had in mind when posted. However, instead of full 3D photo conversion that takes up lot of space, perhaps 2 views in each of   x,y and z viewing directions would suffice to start with.

Comment: @J.M. Some SE sites can embed special content (YouTube, electrical circuits on EE.SE, etc.)  How about making it possible to embed content from SketchFab or similar sites? Example: https://sketchfab.com/models/93bd613578094e1283a959d00eee343a  The problem is that export from Mathematica is still a bit difficult. But it's getting better.

Comment: Wow. If closed form Plot3D surfaces can be done that easy, what is the extra difficulty in diverting 2D, 3D parametric plots as well?

Answer (score 2):

Producing manipulable 3D graphics as in your question is possible, as in [(81104)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81104/can-mathematica-produce-manipulatable-3d-plots-for-deployment-on-the-web), but

1. it's a lot of work,
2. it needs to be done on a per-image basis,
3. it needs specific hosting of large 3D data files,
4. it requires the loading of a large library, and therefore
5. it makes the loading of the page to take much longer, particularly for users on mobile devices.

Each of these would be fatal on its own, so there's no way this will get implemented. At present it would require both (a) extensive additional infrastructure on the site, and (b) per-question work to make the images 3D. You could envision site functionality that took Mathematica code in answers and compiled it into a 3D graphic, but that would require (a') a significant buildout of new code, to make (b') *much* heavier pages. You can ask the Stack Exchange team, but you can probably see what sort of answer you'll get.